# Python: how to swap values of 2 iterators in 2 for loops?

Tags: python, matrix

I have a code that wants to run like this:

```
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):

    if a condition is satisfied:
    let i = j in the next loop, j is reset back to 0
```

Example:
if `i = 0, j = 0` and condition is not met => continue 
if `i = 0, j = 1` and condition is met => let `i = j` 
Next loop: `i = 1, j = 0` then `i = 1, j = 1` and the loop continues.

More example: if `i = 3, j = 2` and condition is met: 
Next loop: `i = 2, j = 3`

Comment: Can you tell us what you’re trying to do with these loops? This seems like a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: I'm finding an Euler path using adjacency matrix using Python. The simplest case was a triangle ABC I can do that, but the rectangle ABCD it printed me the wrong result order, and when I debugged, i did not swap with j.

Answer (score 0):

There is not way of changing `i` in the next for loop iteration. You have to use while loops:

```
i,j = 0,0
while i < 10:
    while j < 10:

    if a condition is satisfied:
    let i = j in the next loop, j is reset back to 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `range()` since it will produce a generator, that doesn't care about the current (edited) value of `i` or `j`.

You can do what you seek like so with a while loop.

```
i = 0
j = 0
while(i < 10):
    j = 0
    while(j < 10):
        if condition:
            i, j = j, i
        j += 1
    i += 1
```

Comment: Your indents are broken.

Comment: are you missing this -> `j is reset back to 0`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `while`:

```
i, j = 0, 0
while i < 10:
    while j < 10:
        if a condition is satisfied:
            i, j = j, i
        j += 1
    i += 1
```